# AWS amplify max number of app quota issue

Tags: aws-amplify

I have AWS amplify and try to deploy a github repo in ap-south-1 resgion but it gives error

> Houston, there's a problem Failed to create app. You have reached the
> maximum number of apps in this account.

while I have only 1 app running and I can see the quote is 25 apps

https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/amplify/quotas

[image: aws amplify issue]

so what could be issue here? someone can help here